# Spring свойство

Tags: java, spring

Всем привет!
Читал в какой-то книжке про **Spring** что есть некое свойство при установки которой не нужно всегда перезапускать проект. То есть ставим свойство в *application.properties* в значение истина и при выполнении каких либо изменении просто перезагружаем страницу в браузере.
Я не помню как называется это свойство. Может кто помнит?

Answer (score 4):

Только если это проект Spring Boot и в classpath находятся [Developer Tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html):

**pom.xml**

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это оно.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)